# Método é executado ao clicar no botão apesar de fazer "button01.Enabled = false"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async

Eu quero desabilitar um botão enquanto o método não termina. Usei `button01.Enabled = false;`, mas mesmo clicando enquanto o botão está desabilitado, o método é chamado de novo depois que termina.

Por exemplo, quando executo o método abaixo e clico três vezes no botão durante os três segundos em que ele está desabilitado aparece "TEST" quatro vezes no *output*.

```
private void buttonSendUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TEST");        

    buttonSendUsers.Enabled = false;

    Thread.Sleep(3000); //teste

    buttonSendUsers.Enabled = true;

    return;
}
```

Como posso fazer com que o botão não execute o método enquanto estiver desabilitado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma pergunta igual a esta no SO e gostei [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586337/221800):

```
button1.Enabled = false;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // execução lenta aqui, se não for lenta, não faz sentido
}).ContinueWith(task => {
    button1.Enabled = true;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/OnOff.cs).

[Tem uma outra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580390/221800).

Answer (score 0):

O código da resposta está certo, mas está de difícil compreensão.

Mais simples:

```cs
private void buttonSendUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonSendUsers.Enabled = false;
    Task.Run(() => {
        // Sua tarefa aqui
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        buttonSendUsers.Enabled = true;
    });
}
```

Se você usar o código acima, terá um erro em tempo de depuração, mas em tempo de execução ele funciona normalmente.

Erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'buttonSendUsers' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.'

O erro é devido à chamada de objetos de interface em uma Thread que não é a da interface, há duas maneiras de não ocorrer o erro:

#### Desabilitando a conferência extra em tempo de depuração

Chame o código seguinte no form (não recomendado fazer isso, pois você pode ter problemas de sincronia):

```cs
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Ele simplesmente desabilita essa conferência em tempo de depuração.

#### Invocando método na Thread da interface

chame:

```
Invoke((Action)(() => { buttonSendUsers.Enabled = true; }));
```

Ou:

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { buttonSendUsers.Enabled = true; }));
```

Para reabilitar o botão, a segunda forma o faz de modo assíncrono.

Código "thread safe":

```cs
private void buttonSendUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonSendUsers.Enabled = false;
    Task.Run(() => {
        // Sua tarefa aqui
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { buttonSendUsers.Enabled = true; }));
    });
}
```